# jquery cluetip breaks when loaded more than once

Tags: jquery, loaded, cluetip

I am using the jQuery cluetip plugin in a portal environment where there can be more than one instance of a portlet on a portal page. Each portlet is its own app, so it really knows nothing about the other portlets. Each portlet needs to use the cluetip plugin, so it is loading it when it needs it. The problem is that, when the cluetip script is loaded more than once, it generates the following error:

```
$cluetip is undefined
```

I know one possible solution is to check whether the plugin is already loaded or not, but every check I have tried fails. I have tried:

```
if(jQuery.cluetip), if(jQuery().cluetip), if(jQuery.fn.cluetip), if(jQuery().fn.cluetip)
```

and none of them work. They all return undefined.

How can I check whether the plugin is already loaded or not? Or, is there another solution that I can implement?

Comment: the plug-in is either built incorrectly or your trying to load the plug-in before jQuery, or even not loading the plug-in at all.

Comment: Do you have a url that can be debugged?

Comment: No public URL that can be seen.

Comment: The issue is that the cluetip plugin is being loaded twice. It is a portal environment and the cluetip plugin is being loaded separately by each portlet using jQuery.getScript(). Thus, portlet 1 loads the plugin and at the same time, portlet 2 loads it. This results in the error in my original post.

Comment: Turns out that both jQuery().cluetip and jQuery.fn.cluetip do return the function. The issue is that the script is being loaded at the same time by each portlet, so when I check to see if the plugin is already defined before I load it again, it returns false. Bummer that the plugin breaks when loaded twice. I am doing the exact same thing with many other plugins and they don't break.

Answer (score 0):

Are you utilizing cluetip inside a document ready function?

```
$(function() {
  $('a.tips').cluetip();
});
```

It doesn't look like you're using cluetip properly based on the code you posted above. You don't really need to check if the plug-in is loaded. If you have the script in your header:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.cluetip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then you just need to select what you want to have a tip on ('a.tips') in my example above, and it should just work.

If you post your Javascript and HTML, I can provide you a better answer.

Comment: Yes, I am loading jquery prior to the plugin and am creating the tips inside of document ready.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source from the cuetip site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.tips').cluetip();

  $('#houdini').cluetip({
    splitTitle: '|', // use the invoking element's title attribute to populate the clueTip...
                     // ...and split the contents into separate divs where there is a "|"
    showTitle: false // hide the clueTip's heading
  });
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.cluetip.css" type="text/css" />
```

Things to notice is that the first thing loaded is jQuery.js, followed by cuetip.

Make sure that your html looks the same, and make sure that the cuetip AND jQuery are loading fine.